# Expressing $xy-zw$ in terms of $z-x$ and $w-y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Short question: is $xy-zw$ expressible in terms of strictly $a,b$ given $a=z-x$ and $b=w-y$? I don't think it is, and any of my attempts to mix together $a$ and $b$ only produce $xy+zw$ up to multiplication by units.

Comment: The usual trick in this situation is to add and subtract a term and hope that something magical happens. We have $xy -yz + yz - zw = y(x - z) + z(y - w) = -ay - bz$. Based on this, I'm doubtful it will be possible. Morally, we could have expected this since we started with $4$ variables: $w,x,y,z$ and only substituted $2$: $a,b$. That leaves $2$ left over that won't go away with substitution, in my case $y$ and $z$.

Comment: I have found $xy+zw$ if that does you any good.